# Disable 'Skip Intro' button in Netflix

Tags: netflix

How can I hide the **Skip Intro** button when watching a show on Netflix?

I never want to skip intros, and don't want to see the bright yellow/orange button.

[image: Skip Intro]

How can I disable the  **Skip Intro** button for all shows?

I would prefer a setting within the Netflix web application to turn it off for the web app player (and also hopefully for client apps such as the Apple TV).

If no such setting exists, I'd be interested in solutions via a 3rd party browser extension to hide page elements such as Ad Blockers.

Comment: This site is for users of Web Apps. Questions about mobile applications are off-topic. I have edited the question to remove unnecessary meta-comments and requirements unrelated to the scope of this site. If Netflix doesn't support this natively and you don't want to run a browser modification to address it, then what kind of solution are you seeking? Does there remain a purpose to the question?  If so please [edit] the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Blindspots - just to clarify, if a question cannot be answered (I.e. the answer is along the lines of “that’s not possible”) is the correct course to close the question or would an answer stating as much be appropriate? The question is “is this possible at the moment” and the answer is “no”. What other details could be added?

Comment: @Blindspots An answer of "Netflix doesn't support this" would be welcome; question should be reopened so such an answer can be posted. Such Q/A is allowed by Stack Exchange. I'm also interested in browser extension solutions.

Comment: @fez Netflix has ~2 options related to TV playback so there is no need to develop a database of missing options. OP is likely aware in their research, all solutions pointed to extensions /browser mods. We can't perform magic, and new feature requests should be directed to the manufacturer HOWEVER the question has been edited to make practical solutions possible so this discussion is now moot since the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm very late, but you can get rid of the skip button by downloading the browser extension uBlock Origin & then right clicking on the skip button & pressing "Block element..." Upon doing this a small window thingy will appear; on it will be an option to "create", once you've pressed it, the skip intro button will be no more!

uBlock Origin (chrome):https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?pli=1